# Mocha test fails without giving proper error

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have setup mocha to run test on my express application. However mocha test fails every time I run npm test without giving any error refer to the screen
[image]

here is my snippet of my package.json, my folder structure and code
[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried running mocha manually also but it doesn't print anything. it just exit the process. lastly i tried running it in the debug mode and here is the log of debug mode

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v14.15.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info lifecycle data-central@1.0.0~pretest: data-central@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle data-central@1.0.0~test: data-central@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle data-central@1.0.0~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle data-central@1.0.0~test: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\The expert Institute\data-central-backend\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Admin\bin;C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Python39;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Terraform;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts
9 verbose lifecycle data-central@1.0.0~test: CWD: E:\The expert Institute\data-central-backend
10 silly lifecycle data-central@1.0.0~test: Args: [ '/d /s /c', "mocha './tests/*.test.js'" ]
11 silly lifecycle data-central@1.0.0~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle data-central@1.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script
13 verbose stack Error: data-central@1.0.0 test: `mocha './tests/*.test.js'`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid data-central@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd E:\The expert Institute\data-central-backend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
18 verbose node v14.15.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.10
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error data-central@1.0.0 test: `mocha './tests/*.test.js'`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the data-central@1.0.0 test script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Operating system - windows 10
Node version - 14 LTS
NPM version - 6.14.10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer to this problem was very quite simple. My node server was already running on port 3000. now when I ran npm test, chai-http was starting the node server again see this line[image]

no two server can run on same port, so my node process was exiting upon port conflict and it wasn't giving me any error that why my test was not working